# Reset People Pane in Microsoft Outlook 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Is it possible to reset the minimized People Pane in Microsoft Outlook 2013?

By default it shows `See more about ...`, but for some reason this PC shows the sender and subject.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, go to View > People Pane > Minimized  (or as I vastly prefer, Off).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to reset people pane in outlook 2013.

Open Outlook 2013. please navigate to

File > Account Settings > E-mail tab > Change...(account) button > more settings button > advanced tab > check 'download shared folders' box > OK > next/finish wizard and finally restart outlook.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What has this got to do with the question?

Comment: You want to reset people pane in outlook 2013?